# How do I populate a 'asp:ListBox' with an array of strings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, listbox

I have an `asp:Listbox` that I need to switch out the items on depending on user selection. Here is what I have tried:

```
 string[] my2012Departments = new string[5];
            my2012Departments[0] = "Administration"; 
            my2012Departments[1] = "Imaging Services"; 
            my2012Departments[2] = "IT"; 
            my2012Departments[3] = "Lab"; 
            my2012Departments[4] = "Support Services";
            lstDSYDepartment.Items.AddRange(my2012Departments.ToArray()); 
           //The AddRange will also not work without .ToArray()
```

This however causes the following errors:

***1. Cannot Convert from 'string[]' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem[]'***

***2.The best overloaded method match for ....AddRange.... has some invalid arguments***

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288424(v=vs.71).aspx) this should work as long as I put the code in the form load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you refer to is for Windows Forms, not for ASP.

Try

```
lstDSYDepartment.Items.Add("Administration");
lstDSYDepartment.Items.Add("Imaging Services");
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `List<string>` and assign that as the datasource for your listbox like below

```
List<string> my2012Departments = new List<string>();
my2012Departments.Add("Administration");
my2012Departments.Add("Imaging Services");
my2012Departments.Add("IT");
my2012Departments.Add("Lab");
my2012Departments.Add("Support Services");


lstDSYDepartment.DataSource = my2012Departments;
lstDSYDepartment.DataBind();
```

(OR) Instead of assigning a string array; create a array of `ListItem[]` like below

```
ListItem[] my2012Departments = new ListItem[5];
    my2012Departments[0] = "Administration"; 
    my2012Departments[1] = "Imaging Services"; 
    my2012Departments[2] = "IT"; 
    my2012Departments[3] = "Lab"; 
    my2012Departments[4] = "Support Services";

  this.lstDSYDepartment.Items.AddRange(my2012Departments);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried this and I kept getting the same two errors.

Comment: That's not possible; not at least with the 2nd option I have provided in answer (the `OR` part). You got that error cause `AddRange` method expects type `listitem[]`. That shows you didn't tried the 2nd option at all :)

Comment: i tried both...i got errors for both...more for the second option. I upvoted your answer though as I appreciate your time and assistance.